# How can I specify a specific value in a column retrieved via php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to add an if statement regarding the 'type' column. Is there something after the `.attr('type')` which will allow me to specify a particular value for type?

```
$.get("map_process.php", function (data) {
            $(data).find("marker").each(function () {
                  var name      = $(this).attr('name');
                  var address   = '<p>'+ $(this).attr('address') +'</p>';
                  var type      = $(this).attr('type');
```

So `$(this).attr('type');` is loading all the rows in my tables 'type' column value. eg:
**Table**
**Name, Address, Type***
Name1, Address1, TypeA,
Name2, Address2, TypeB,
Name3, Address3, TypeA,
etc

How can I 'get access' to what actually the value of the 'type' column; eg. `$(this).attr('type').<something>('TypeA');`

Is this possible?

Edit2: map_process.php end

```
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo 'description="' . parseToXML($row['description']) . '" ';

  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Your question is not clear.

Comment: You mean the **type** of the tag: b, input, div ...?

Comment: Sorry I mean, above I am just loading each value of my table into a google map, and am using the values for what are in the 'type' column of my table to display in the infobox. But say for instance, I only wanted to load markers that have a specific value (within the table) to my map.

Comment: Show a part of the result of `map_process.php`.

Comment: I thought, you need to load specific type from your markers table right? (i.e TypeA markers only)

Comment: @KrishR Initially, I would like to load all, but then when a check box(specific type) is checked(on the main html page) I would like to only display those markers on the map. Would it be better to hide markers from the map dependent on these values? But I will still need to be able to access the specific type within the db. eg, `hide typeA if checkA = true, else show`

Comment: You can send the selected checkbox value into map_process.php and get the selected value from table and update the markers again in Map.

Answer (score 0):

You have **two** options:

**(1)** If you have full control over the ajax page you are calling, the best solution would be to:

> "send the selected checkbox value into map_process.php and get the
>   selected value from table and update the markers again in Map." – 
>   Krish R

```
//jQuery
var cbVal = "TYPEA"; //Assign with checkbox value's associated string
$.get("map_process.php?checkboxval=" + cbVal, function (data) 
{ 
    //do something with the data returned
});

//PHP
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers where type = '".$_GET["checkboxval"]."'";
```

**(2)** If you don't have control over the source of the ajax call (for example from a third party source), OR you want to return all markers every time, consider using the [jQuery Filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
//jQuery
var cbVal = "TYPEA"; //Assign with checkbox value's associated string
$(data).filter(function(index,val) 
{
    return $(val).attr('type') === cbVal;
}).each(function () 
{
    //do something with the data returned
});
```

See the example for option (2) on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Psylene/7embw0kf/2/)